# Working with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

Will this program delete all the contents of RAM? I dared not to run it on my PC. And there was no use of doing it on online compilers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a = 10;

    int *p;
    p = &a;

    for(int i = 0;i>=0;i++){
        *(p+i) = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many times do you think the loop will execute?

Comment: You're lucky that the loop will never run, because writing to memory you don't own leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: It's not that simple. There is much to read if you are interested: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: Run it on any modern computer you want. Memory allocated to different processes are protected from other processes. Depending on your background, you may find it useful to pick up a good operating systems book and read up process management and memory management.

Comment: i have edited the question and made for loop work. Sorry guys :)

Comment: I ran this and all of the contents of my RAM were indeed deleted. I was able to bring them back from Recycle Bin though.

Comment: Yep - don't do it. This is a highly risky malware code which will delete your OS and make your RAM burn in flames!

*Of course I'm joking. Normally, if you compile application as targeting some OS it'll only access a limited address of the RAM where the program is loaded, so you couldn't destroy the kernel processes or something - at least this is in Windows. But you should know that this is not guaranteed by the C++ standard itself, so if you OS allow it or you're making for example a driver app - nasty things could really happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a program can only touch memory inside its virtual address space, so no, this program will not "delete all of RAM" even if that were possible for some definition of "delete".

#### Here is what I would expect to happen.

1. It eventually crashes with a segfault when it tries to write into read-only memory.
2. If you have a 64-bit address space, the loop will terminate once the `int` wraps around to the negatives. The program should at that point crash because you have overwritten the return address for the function `main`.

#### Here is what I observed to actually happen on my system, when the program is compiled without optimizations.

- The program loops indefinitely without crashing and without making progress, because it appears that  `p + 1 == &i` under my system. Thus, the loop perpetuates indefinitely, because `i` gets reset to `0` after every iteration of the body of the loop, and increments to `1` at the end of the loop.
- To observe this, I compiled with `-g`, and inside `gdb`, I interrupted the program with `Control-C` and printed `p + i` and `&i` and observed that they were the same.

Note that my observation may be specific to my system and is *definitely* specific to my compiler options.

Answer (score 0):

On modern machines / OS's, each process has it's own virtual address space. One job of the OS is to map sections (pages) of this address space to real memory, and to swap out unused areas to disk. This is what allows multiple programs with memory demands far greater than the physical RAM to all run at once. It's also what causes "disk thrashing" if you don't have enough RAM, as the OS is constantly having to read and write pages of memory to the swap file.

This also protects the rest of the system from badly written programs. One process cannot affect memory used by another. Only the bad one will crash.

Additionally, areas of memory within the virtual address space can have access modifiers. For instance, Windows will use some of the memory to store the code that is being run. You don't want to be accidentally writing over this code, so it gets marked as readonly. This is why you will get an access violation if you attempt to write to address 0, even though address 0 is in your virtual address space.